# Dynamically Insert into Table A Based on Row_Num from Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I've condensed some data into TableB which looks like the following:

```
+========+==========+=========+
| AreaID | AreaName | Row_Num | 
+========+==========+=========+
|   506  | BC-VanW  |    1    |
+--------+----------+---------+
|   3899 | BC-VicS  |    2    |
+--------+----------+---------+
|   1253 | AB-CalW  |    3    |
+--------+----------+---------+
```

There are 2000 unique rows in total, Row_Num from 1 to 2000, and every AreaID in this table is naturally unique as well.

I now want to insert into a blank table, TableA, which has the following columns:

```
+========+==========+=========+============+===========+
| AreaID | StartDT  |  EndDT  | MarketCode |Allocation |
+========+==========+=========+============+===========+
```

The insert statement I want to use is repeats everything except for the AreaID

I was attempting some things earlier and this is a basic look at what I have that I'm hoping Stackoverflow could help me expand on:

```
DECLARE @AreaID NVARCHAR(4)
SET @AreaID = (SELECT AreaID FROM TableB WHERE Row_Num = 1)

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Sql = N'                   
INSERT INTO TableA (AreaID, StartDt, EndDt, MarketCode, Allocation) VALUES ('+@AreaID+', ''2020-11-01 00:00:00.000'', ''2049-12-31 00:00:00.000'' , 31 , 25.00);
INSERT INTO TableA (AreaID, StartDt, EndDt, MarketCode, Allocation) VALUES ('+@AreaID+', ''2020-11-01 00:00:00.000'', ''2049-12-31 00:00:00.000'' , 38 , 60.00);
INSERT INTO TableA (AreaID, StartDt, EndDt, MarketCode, Allocation) VALUES ('+@AreaID+', ''2020-11-01 00:00:00.000'', ''2049-12-31 00:00:00.000'' , 39 , 15.00);
'
EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
GO
```

From here I would want it to 'loop' through the Row_Nums, once and once only, and run the full insert query above eventually doing it for all 2000 Row_Nums.

Of course, if there is a more efficient way please let me know and I will take a look.

Thanks!

Comment: Aside: A great way to meet [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) is to concatenate data into a dynamic SQL statement. Using [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with parameters is a safe way to handle parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a cross join with a fixed list of values:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (AreaID, StartDt, EndDt, MarketCode, Allocation)
SELECT b.AreaID, x.*
FROM tableB b
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
    ('2020-11-01 00:00:00.000', '2049-12-31 00:00:00.000', 31, 25.00),
    ('2020-11-01 00:00:00.000', '2049-12-31 00:00:00.000', 38, 60.00),
    ('2020-11-01 00:00:00.000', '2049-12-31 00:00:00.000', 39, 15.00)
) x(StartDt, EndDt, MarketCode, Allocation)
```

If the date range is always the same, this can be simplified a little:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (AreaID, StartDt, EndDt, MarketCode, Allocation)
SELECT b.AreaID, '2020-11-01 00:00:00.000', '2049-12-31 00:00:00.000', x.*
FROM tableB b
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
    (31 , 25.00),
    (38 , 60.00),
    (39 , 15.00)
) x(MarketCode, Allocation)
```